# Unable to pre-select select value

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have a web page with a drop down list. I have a JSFiddle of my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4ynLv3xb/2/). The drop-down list is rendered with the [select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) plugin. I need to support tags in the drop-down list. My drop-down list works fine during the initial (create) state). However, when I am editing a record, I cannot figure out how to pre-populate the selected value. I tried following the example from the docs which had the following:

```
$('#NameDisplay').select2({
  tags: ["Randy"]
});
```

However, as my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ynLv3xb/2/) shows, it doesn't work. I included a "Basic" drop-down just to try to get something to populate. I also included a "Complete" to better show my entire scenario. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the `value` attribute of the `<input>` element. Set it to a comma-separated list of the tags.

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="NameDisplay"
       name="NameDisplay" type="text" value="Randy" />
```

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much. It was driving me NUTs.